# Troll in profile

Tags: discussion, user-profile

[Profile in question.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/9293/crazy-eddie)

This guy's bio contains the following:

> programmers.SE, where 2/3 of all questions are summarily closed.
>
> Why am I here? I like to piss off twits. Does that make you mad?

What do we do with that? That is trolling in my opinion...

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw57Q.jpg]

Comment: Oh Eddie! Don't worry about him, he's crazy ;P

Comment: Well, it would probably help to not fall into his trap and in some sense vindicating his point.

Comment: I totally upvoted this question :P

Comment: I think it's the impression that many people get. Me included. This site is over-moderated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I went browsing Meta SO for any profile rules, and it appears there really aren't any. A user's profile is a reflection of the user, not a reflection of the site.

You can put pretty much anything in there, [even profanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31209/158605), although since it is a reflection of the you, you may want to consider carefully what you put in there.

[Rules for Profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31504/158605)

> Generally speaking, your profile is (to an extent) fair game, as it is
>   a reflection of you as a person, not the site as a whole.
>
> Self-promotion, your e-mail address, humor, (if you know HTML) imagery
>   and even the f-bomb are allowed there.
>
> There are reasonable limitations for all of those, but generally
>   speaking, unless you're a hard-core spammer or you put something truly
>   offensive / crazy in there (like hate speech or pornography), you'll
>   be OK.

Answer (score 17):

The person is known to us.

However, the profile is where a user can say (almost) what they like and this doesn't come anywhere close to crossing that line.

I'd just ignore it - most people don't view user profiles anyway.